# I cannot pass an onClick event in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I am trying to mutate my component with relay in this code but I don't know why I can't put an onClick event on the lists

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new createTodoMutation({
        text: this.refs.textForNewTodo.value,
        store: this.props.store
      })
    );
    this.refs.textForNewTodo.value="";
  }
  handleOnClick = (id) => {
    id.preventDefault();
    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new toggleTodoStatus({
        id: id,
        store: this.props.store
      })
    );
  }
  render() {
    let todolist = this.props.store.todoConnection.edges.map((edge) => {
      return (
        <li key={edge.node.id} onClick={this.handleOnClick(edge.node.id)}>
          <p>{edge.node.text}</p>
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Todos</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Todo text" ref="textForNewTodo" />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        Showing: &nbsp;
        <select onChange={this.setLimit} defaultValue={this.props.relay.variables.limit}>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <ul>
          {todolist}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
```

handleSubmit is working but handleOnClick on lists is not and I am having this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" but I am passing edge.node.id upon invokation by onClick={this.handleOnClick(edge.node.id)}. I can't see what's wrong in this code. help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a wrong way of passing `onClick` event. When you do `onClick={this.handleOnClick(edge.node.id)}`, the event will only be invoked once during rendering.

Try `onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(edge.node.id)}`.

Comment: I still have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined error :(

Comment: @iamnewbie Is that error from the `onClick` line? That means your `edge` doesn't have a property called `node`. Try logging it out?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are calling the **handleOnClick** immediately after each render, instead of passing it to the **onClick** so it can call it whenever you click on that element.

since you need to pass a parameter to your function you CANNOT simply pass the function to onClick

```
<... onClick={this.handleOnClick} />
```

So to resolve this issue, you can create an arrow function and the pass the arrow function to onClick

```
<... onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(edge.node.id)} />
```

you also don't need the id.preventDefault(); anymore